# Excluding array parameters in stamp

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to sort the result of a string to show only a specific parameter.

I also want to exclude the `idle` and `_total` process from the result

```
$list = (Get-Counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time').CounterSamples | Where-Object {$_.CookedValue -gt 1}
```

How can I do that? I already tried to use the `clear-variable` and the `sort` function but every time I run those i keep getting an error.

Sorry for the bad english :)

Comment: The function is this one:
$list = (Get-Counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time').CounterSamples | Where-Object {$_.CookedValue -gt 1}

Comment: You might want to edit the question and add the details in it.

Comment: I put the function in the comments, i cant put the function in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this -

```
$list | where-object {$_.InstanceName -notmatch 'idle' -and $_.InstanceName -notmatch '_total'}
```

Or you can add the condition in your code itself -

```
$list = (Get-Counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time').CounterSamples | Where-Object {$_.CookedValue -gt 1 -and $_.InstanceName -notmatch 'idle' -and $_.InstanceName -notmatch '_total'}
```

In both ways, you can exclude `idle` and `_total` from your search result and then sort it as per your need.

To include `CPU%` from `WmiObject` and excluding `idle` and `_total` from your search, you can exclude them directly while you are querying the `WmiObject` as below -

```
$properties=@( @{Name="Process Name"; Expression = {$_.name}}, @{Name="CPU (%)"; Expression = {$_.PercentProcessorTime}}, @{Name="Memory (MB)"; Expression ={[Math]::Round(($_.workingSetPrivate / 1mb),2)}} )

Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process | Where-Object {$_.Name -notmatch 'Idle' -and $_.Name -notmatch '_total'} | Select-Object $properties | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, i had to change the script in order to use the cpu %, now i have this -
cls
$properties=@(
   @{Name="Process Name"; Expression = {$_.name}},
 #@{Name="Process Name"; Expression = {$_.name -and $_.name -notmatch 'idle' -and $_.name -notmatch '_total'}},
    @{Name="CPU (%)"; Expression = {$_.PercentProcessorTime}},    
    @{Name="Memory (MB)"; Expression = {[Math]::Round(($_.workingSetPrivate / 1mb),2)}}
)Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process|Select-Object $properties | Format-Table -AutoSize
Do you know how i can filter this without idle & total?

Comment: @JustNejih: See the edited answer. Hope that helps! :)